# Windows batch files not running completely when double clicking

Tags: batch-file, pipe

I see this question has been asked from time to time, but no answer has been given which solves the problem for me.

The following batch reproduces the problem

```
@echo off
sleep 2
dir /s /b > FileList.txt
```

When running batch from command line it runs as expected. It sleeps for 2sec and then creates the file **FileList.txt**

But when double clicking in file browser, then only the sleep command seems to execute. The **FileList.txt** does not get created. The Dir command is executing, but the file is not created.

I have tried by running with admin rights to no help.

```
cmd /c assoc .bat
```

gives

```
.bat=batfile
```

Registry has been checked and found OK. So...
Is there a way to get batch files run by clicking on them to also handle file operations? Because thats what I believe is the issue here that something is preventing file operations to happen when evoked from a batch script which runs from within a file browser.

Comment: Did you try to use an absolute path `dir > C:\temp\FileList.txt`?

Comment: If you where here I would give you a hugh!
Yes, it solves it.. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

When starting a batch by double click from the explorer the working directory hasn't be the same as the batch file itself.

You can solve this by using an absolute path

```
@echo off
sleep 2
dir /s /b > c:\temp\FileList.txt
```

or by changing the working directory to the batch location.

```
@echo off
cd "%~dp0"
sleep 2
dir /s /b > FileList.txt
```